# Laravel collapsible sidebar

Tags: web, bootstrap-4, responsive

I need a collapsible sidebar on my bootstrap project. I want to be able to click the top button on the left blue bar, and make all the contents in the sidebar to collapse or show. I need this to work in mobile aswell. Can't really find any solutions that don't envolve cloning a git repo and stuff like that. What is the easiest way to do this?[image]

Edit: my code doesn't really matter for the question, I used bootstrap's grid system to make a simple preview for this question

Comment: Bootstrap has an experimental example on how to do this with their collapse js. You can see it on this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/offcanvas/ but you have to resize your browser to be smaller

Comment: @Turqueso that seems perfect! But where is the code to it? Can't find it anywhere

Comment: You can download the example on their page and inspect it. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was mentioned in one of the comments on my post, bootstrap has developed an experimental example, exactly as I described. This can be found in the following link: getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/offcanvas